# Event Handling Problems - Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm having major trouble right now with my program. I don't understand this error message "MyEventA is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.actionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener." I have tried looking online and in my textbook and I still can't get it working.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me figure out what is wrong with my code. I have been working on this for and hour and a half and still haven't fixed it. :( Thanks in advance!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyEventA extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton plus;
    private JButton minus;
    private JButton reset;
    private JButton quit;

    public MyEventA()
{
    add(new JLabel("Current Value", JLabel.LEFT), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JTextField jtfCurrent = new JTextField("0");
    add(jtfCurrent, BorderLayout.EAST);
    JPanel jpSouth = new JPanel();
    plus = new JButton("+");
    minus = new JButton("-");
    reset = new JButton("Reset");
    quit = new JButton("Quit");
    ButtonListener b1 = new ButtonListener(jtfCurrent);
    jtfCurrent.addActionListener(b1);
    plus.addActionListener(this);
    minus.addActionListener(this);
    reset.addActionListener(this);
    quit.addActionListener(this);
    jpSouth.add(plus);
    jpSouth.add(minus);
    jpSouth.add(reset);
    jpSouth.add(quit);
    add(jpSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField writeInto;   // text field reference
    private int count = 0;

    public ButtonListener(JTextField tf) {
        writeInto = tf;
        count = 0;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("+")){
            count++;
            writeInto.setText("" + count);
        }
        else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("-")){
            count--;
            writeInto.setText("" + count);
        }
        else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Reset")){
            count = 0;
            writeInto.setText("" + count);
        }
        else {
            System.exit(0);    
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyEventA events = new MyEventA();
        events.setTitle("Part 2 Using getSource");
        events.pack();
        events.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        events.setSize(300,100);
        events.setLocation(200,200);
        events.setVisible(true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Forgetting about abstract classes for a second, what have you learned about what interfaces are, and what should be done when a class implements one?

Comment: Do you know what does 'implements' mean in Java? And how a class implements an interface?

Answer (score 2):

In general, when a (non-abstract) class `implements` an interface, a contract is made suggesting that this class will implement all methods provided in the interface.

Your class `MyEventA` `implements` the interface `ActionListener`, which requires a method to be overridden (`void actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`).  Since `MyEventA` is not abstract, the compiler is telling you that you need to implement the method here.

If you are wondering how you can implement the method, you have a good example in your subclass (`ButtonListener`) of an implementation.  Here you can see that `ButtonListener` implements the same interface, `ActionListener`, and implements its method.

Comment: what so why is the method not being overridden even though I have a ButtonListener class that would implement it>

Comment: The class `ButtonListener` is a different class than `MyEventA`.  It is implemented in one, and not the other.

Comment: wait but I see that both MyEventA and ButtonListener implement ActionListener.

Answer (score 1):

You must override actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) method if you are implementing ActionListener interface.The compiler asks the class to be declared as abstarct if the method in interface is not overridden.

Comment: Well, I thought I was overriding, but now I'm just generally confused. How am I not overriding it?

Answer (score 1):

Because `MyEventA` has implemented `ActionListener` and because it is not an abstract class it must implement / define the method `actionPeformed (ActionEvent)` much in the same way you have done in `ButtonListener`

But I think what you want to do is actually not have `MyEventA` implement `ActionListener` and instead pass a `new ButtonListener ()` to your buttons like

```
plus.addListener (new ButtonListener ());
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as follows, it works for me:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyEventA extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton plus;
    private JButton minus;
    private JButton reset;
    private JButton quit;

    public MyEventA() {
        add(new JLabel("Current Value", JLabel.LEFT), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JTextField jtfCurrent = new JTextField("0");
        add(jtfCurrent, BorderLayout.EAST);
        JPanel jpSouth = new JPanel();
        plus = new JButton("+");
        minus = new JButton("-");
        reset = new JButton("Reset");
        quit = new JButton("Quit");
        ButtonListener b1 = new ButtonListener(jtfCurrent);
        jtfCurrent.addActionListener(b1);
        plus.addActionListener(this);
        minus.addActionListener(this);
        reset.addActionListener(this);
        quit.addActionListener(this);
        jpSouth.add(plus);
        jpSouth.add(minus);
        jpSouth.add(reset);
        jpSouth.add(quit);
        add(jpSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        private JTextField writeInto; // text field reference
        private int count = 0;

        public ButtonListener(JTextField tf) {
            writeInto = tf;
            count = 0;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("+")) {
                count++;
                writeInto.setText("" + count);
            } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("-")) {
                count--;
                writeInto.setText("" + count);
            } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Reset")) {
                count = 0;
                writeInto.setText("" + count);
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// was to be implemented

        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "clicked");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {// main method should be in the outer class
        MyEventA events = new MyEventA();
        events.setTitle("Part 2 Using getSource");
        events.pack();
        events.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        events.setSize(300, 100);
        events.setLocation(200, 200);
        events.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

If you want to use the `actionPerformed` in `ButtonListener` class, use the below code :

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyEventA extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton plus;
    private JButton minus;
    private JButton reset;
    private JButton quit;   


    public MyEventA() {
        add(new JLabel("Current Value", JLabel.LEFT), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JTextField jtfCurrent = new JTextField("0");
        add(jtfCurrent, BorderLayout.EAST);
        JPanel jpSouth = new JPanel();
        plus = new JButton("+");
        minus = new JButton("-");
        reset = new JButton("Reset");
        quit = new JButton("Quit");     


        ButtonListener b1 = new ButtonListener(jtfCurrent);
        jtfCurrent.addActionListener(b1);
        plus.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(jtfCurrent));
        minus.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(jtfCurrent));
        reset.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(jtfCurrent));
        quit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(jtfCurrent));
        jpSouth.add(plus);
        jpSouth.add(minus);
        jpSouth.add(reset);
        jpSouth.add(quit);
        add(jpSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        private JTextField writeInto; // text field reference
        private int count = 0;
        public ButtonListener() {

        }
        public ButtonListener(JTextField tf) {
            writeInto = tf;
            count = 0;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("+")) {
                count++;
                writeInto.setText("" + count);
            } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("-")) {
                count--;
                writeInto.setText("" + count);
            } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Reset")) {
                count = 0;
                writeInto.setText("" + count);
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "clicked");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyEventA events = new MyEventA();
        events.setTitle("Part 2 Using getSource");
        events.pack();
        events.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        events.setSize(300, 100);
        events.setLocation(200, 200);
        events.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```